# What are some general rules for astrophotography?

Tags: aperture, camera-settings, astrophotography, iso, f-stop

What are the generally accepted guidelines for iso, f-stop, aperture, etc. that help take better pictures of the stars? In the past I've mostly used a small webcam that fits over the eyepiece of my telescopes, but I can't easily transport a scope (without risking damage to it.) I'm usually looking at individual planets, nebulae, or constellations, but that type of magnification is not really possible with just a camera as far as I know. What settings should I use for targeting star clusters or the whole night sky?

For reference, the camera is a Canon Rebel SL1 and I have 18-55 and 75-300 58mm lenses and a pretty solid tripod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two general rules:

**getting the exposure right**: I usually start with f2 shutter speed of 15 seconds and ISO 1600 and adjust form there.

**getting no stars trails** divide 600 by your effective focal length to get the maximum exposure time for getting stars without trails (for your lens at the widest setting: 18mm, gives a 28mm effective full frame focal length, so a maximum of around 20 seconds exposure time in order to not get star trails)